# infix to postfix expression converting code not working

Tags: c++

Following is my code in cpp to convert infix to postfix expression? I have tried everything but my code is not giving me the desired result?  Please somebody help me....plzzzzzz.

It is just not working although I think that the code is right. I have spent a lot of time in checking this code and have checked the working of evry line but still it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int k=-1,m=0;
int j=0;
string infi,postfi,operato;
int precedence(char s)
{
    switch(s)
    {

    case '+':
    case '-':     
    return 1;
    break;
    case '*':
    case '/':     
    return 2;
    break;
    case '$':
    return 3;
    break;
    case '(':
    return 4;
    break;
    case ')':
    return 5;
    break;
    }
}
void operat()
{
     if(k==-1)
     {

              k++;
             operato[k]=infi[j];
             //cout<<operato[0]<<"mm";
     }
     else if(precedence(infi[j])==4)
     {
          //cout<<"0000";
          k++;
          operato[k]=infi[j];
     }
     else if(precedence(infi[j])==5)
     {
          //cout<<"0000";
          while(operato[k]!='(')
          {
                                 postfi[m]=operato[k];
                                 m++;
                                 k--;
          }
          k--;
     }   
     else if(precedence(infi[j])>precedence(operato[k]))
     {
          //cout<<"0000";
          k++;
          operato[k]=infi[j];
     }
     else
     {
         //cout<<"0000";
         postfi[m]=operato[k];
         k--;
         m++;
         operat();
     }
  //cout<<postfi[0]<<"pp";   
}

int main()
{

    cin>>infi;

    while(infi[j]!='\0')
    {
                         if(infi[j]=='+'||infi[j]=='-'||infi[j]=='*'||infi[j]=='/'||infi[j]=='('||infi[j]==')'||infi[j]=='$')
                         {
                                 operat();
                                 j++;
                         }
                         else
                         {

                             postfi[m]=infi[j];
                             //cout<<postfi[0];
                             //cout<<"me"<<m<<postfi[m];
                             m++;
                             j++;
                         }
    }
    while(k!=-1)
    {
                postfi[m]=operato[k];
                //cout<<postfi[0];
                //cout<<"me"<<m;
                //cout<<"meow"<<m<<postfi[m];
                k--;
                m++;
    }
    //cout<<postfi[0];
    int g;
    for(g=0;g<m;g++)
     cout<<postfi[g];
    //getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: General suggestion, try using a debugger where you can step through the code line by line and set breakpoints to see what's going on.

Comment: actually i tried doing that and i cant make out that even while checking the test case a+b, its giving out +b+ and not the right answer which is ab+, i just cant make out why its doing so...:(

Comment: What is it supposed to output?
What's the general goal here?

Comment: it is supposed to convert an infix expression into a postfix expression that is the order of evaluation e.g. if the input is a+b*c then the output will be abc*+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept it as original as I could to what you had posted, so that you could follow it. Modify it to do as you need it to do, I didn't optimize, I did not use STL (since I assume this is homework since you're not using STL), and I wrote it to get it functional vs proper. As I said, you'll have to play with it to get the precedence that you wish, but it's functional as I said. Also on my assumption that it's homework: I didn't complete it either, just putting you in the right direction hopefully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;



int precedence(char s)
{
    int rVal = -1; //Let's assume we didn't succeed
    switch(s)
    {
    case '+':
            rVal = 7;
            break;
    case '-':
            rVal = 6;
            break;
    case '*':
            rVal = 5;
            break;
    case '/':
            rVal = 4;
            break;
    case '^':
            rVal = 3;
            break;
    case '(':
            rVal = 2;
            break;
    case ')':
            rVal = 1;
            break;
    default:
            break;
    }
    return rVal; //This satisfies the warning
}

char getpres(int num)
{
    char rVal = 0;
    switch(num)
    {
    case 7:
            rVal = '+';
            break;
    case 6:
            rVal = '-';
            break;
    case 5:
            rVal = '*';
            break;
    case 4:
            rVal = '/';
            break;
    case 3:
            rVal = '^';
            break;
    case 2:
            rVal = '(';
            break;
    case 1:
            rVal = ')';
            break;
    default:
            break;
    }
    return rVal; //This satisfies the warning
}

string reorder(string temp)
{

    string rVal = "\0";
    int *array = new int[temp.length()];
    unsigned int d = 0;
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x <= temp.length(); ++x )
    {
        array[x] = precedence(temp[x]);
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0;i< temp.length() +1;i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 1;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(array[i] > array[j])
                {
                    d = array[i]; //swap

                    array[i]=array[j];
                    array[j]=d;
                }

            }

        }
        d = 0;
        for(; d < temp.length(); ++d)
        {
            rVal += getpres(array[d]);
        }
        return rVal;
}

int main()
{

    int itr=0;
    string infi = "" ,postfi = "" ,operato = "";
    std::cin>>infi;

    while(itr <= infi.length())
    {
        if(precedence(infi[itr]) > -1)
        {
            operato += infi[itr];
        }
        else
        {
            postfi += infi[itr];
        }
        ++itr;
    }


    postfi += reorder(operato);
    std::cout<<postfi<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i couldnt understand what you are doing since it is very different from the logic what i have used(i may be wrong) but i really couldnt understand it....one thing more can u please tell me what is wrong in my code since to me my code should work but it is not working.. please help me if u can....and thanks for taking time to write the code...:)

Comment: What I ended up fixing was in your switch statement you were lacking control exits for when you found certain chars. 
Global variables that got modified under very odd conditions.
Excessive loops  (especially the one that printed the string at the end).
`infi[j]!='\0'` never found '\0', so it'd crash (for me).

Other than that, double check your logic of parsing the strings and some other minor things is the only thing else I added (Oh and a bubble sort for the order of operations precedence)